# How to correctly bubble up exceptions from Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, task

I'm trying to write an async method which reads an item from a database and provides some amount of validation before and after the read.  The happy path works no problem, but I'm having trouble working out how to correctly throw exceptions.

Here's my code:

```
    protected override async Task<Entity> InternalRead<TEntity>(object id)
    {
        var result = this.context.Set<Entity>().FindAsync(id);
        return await result;
    }

    public Task<TEntity> Read<Entity>(object id) where TEntity : class
    {
        return InternalRead<Entity>(id)
            .ContinueWith(entityTask => 
            {
                var entity = entityTask.Result;
                if (entity != null && !entity.IsHidden)
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

                return entity;
            });
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task InvalidIdThrowsExpectedException()
    {
        var db = *getDBCode*
        var identity = new Identity();
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<UnauthorizedAccessException>(() => accessor.Read<TradingStyle>(1, identity));
    }
```

The Entity with id `1` is hidden, and when I step through the code I can see that the exception is thrown as expected, but the test is seeing `AggregateException` being thrown and not `UnauthorizedAccessException`.  I can't see what's different between my setup and the examples I've been reading, but I'm confused why Assert.ThrowAsync isn't unwrapping the internal exception.

Comment: Try making the lambda also an async/await function: `await Assert.ThrowsAsync<UnauthorizedAccessException>(async () => await accessor.Read<TradingStyle>(1, identity));
 `

Comment: Shouldn't async method in  `ThrowsAsync` be called like `async () => await ` ?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `ContinueWith`; use `await` instead. This is a good general rule for most async code. `ContinueWith` is a low-level method with surprising default behavior; `await` works the way you expect it to:

```
public async Task<TEntity> Read<Entity>(object id) where TEntity : class
{
  var entity = await InternalRead<Entity>(id);
  if (entity != null && !entity.IsHidden)
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

  return entity;
}
```

Comment: @Andy and its less code and, I find it easier to read.